# Please, help me fix the error

Tags: ruby

I am stuck at billions. The error is:
**expected**: "one billion two hundred thirty four million five hundred sixty seven thousand eight hundred ninety"
**got:** "one billion two hundred thirty four million " (using ==)

here is my code:

```
class Fixnum

def in_words
    less_than_13={0 => 'zero', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six', 7=> 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine', 10 => 'ten', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve', 13 => 'thirteen'}
    tens={20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty', 40 => 'forty', 50 => 'fifty', 60 => 'sixty', 70 => 'seventy', 80 => 'eighty', 90 => 'ninety'}
    case self 
    when 0..13
        return less_than_13[self]
    when 14, 16, 17, 19
        return teenify
    when 15
        return 'fifteen'
    when 18
        return 'eighteen'
    when 20, 30, 40, 50 , 60, 70, 80, 90
        return tens[self]
    when (20..99)
        # tens = (self / 10) * 10
        # tens = (77 / 10) * 10
        # tens = (7) * 10
        # tens = 70
        tens = (self / 10) * 10
        # ones = self - tens
        # ones = 77 - 70
        # ones = 7
        ones = self - tens
        return "#{tens.in_words} #{ones.in_words}"
    when (100..999)
        # 100
        hundreds = self / 100
        rest = self - (hundreds * 100)
        if rest > 0
            return "#{hundreds.in_words} hundred #{rest.in_words}"
        else
            return "#{hundreds.in_words} hundred"
        end

        when (999..99999)
        thousend = self / 1000
        rest = self - (thousend * 1000)
            if rest > 0
            return "#{thousend.in_words} thousand #{rest.in_words}"
            else
            return "#{thousend.in_words} thousand"
            end

        when (10000001..999999999)
        million = self / 1000000
        rest = self - (million * 1000000)
            if rest > 0
            return "#{million.in_words} million #{rest.in_words}"
            else
            return "#{million.in_words} million"
            end

        when (1234567890..999999999999)
        billion = self / 1000000000
        rest = self - (billion * 1000000000)
            if rest > 0
            return "#{billion.in_words} billion #{rest.in_words}"
            else
            return "#{billion.in_words} billion"
            end

    end


end
def teenify
    return (self - 10).in_words + 'teen'
end
end
```

Comment: please set a better question title. the title should be expressive and quickly summarize what this question is about. Almost every question could be titled 'Help me'

Comment: and please correct the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some big gaps in your number ranges. Look at them and see which one the number 567,890 would fall into. Answer: None of them. And for that matter, neither would 1,000,000 or 1,000,000,000. It skips right from 99,999 to 10,000,001, and then from 999,999,999 to 1,234,567,890.

Comment: Thank you veru much ! )
I fixed thousends and all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peak at your ranges, They seem to be all over the place after 10,000. I would suggest putting powers so you can see what ranges you expect easier.  for example Millions range is `(10000001..999999999)` and should be 
`(10**6...10**9)`